# Adding Keypress/keydown event on dynamic html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following `dynamic input html` in my project

```
  $(this).html("<input type='text' style='width:35px;' value='" + $(this).text() + "' />");
```

Now i was trying to add **validation for using only numeric** in above input text field.

**But being new to jquery** i was wondering how do i **add keypress event** to it

Want to use following validation to it

```
function isNumber(evt) {
    evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I tried follwoing but does not seem to work

```
$(this).html("<input type='text'  onkeypress='return isNumber(event)' style='width:35px;' value='" + $(this).text() + "' />");
```

**EDIT**

**Any other way to add validation for using only number**

Comment: @ViktorBahtev Seriously?? I don't see any connection between this 2 questions

Comment: You want to add event on dynamic generated elements right? In the suggested thread is described exactly how to do it. Attach the event on some existing DOM element and delegate it to the elements that you want - $(document).on('keypress', 'myactualselector', eventHandler);

Comment: @Richa You might want to provide the code where you're appending the `HTML` to distinguish it from the delegation questions… Hope the answer helps.

Comment: @Richa hey Richa... try custom designs like flatty.. u need not have to write new codes for this kind of validations.. they provide almost every basic stuffs.. wen i got one..u wer d one dat came to ma mind at first..

Answer (score 4):

Use **[event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)**

```
$(document).on("keypress","input[type=text]",isNumber);

// $(document) use closest parent for this
```

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a
>   parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a
>   selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the
>   future.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that, you're executing the shared code in an event of parent element such as click.

So when you click the textbox, the click (*or similar event*) is bubbled to it's parent, hence triggering the handler which replaces the textbox with a new one.

You can prevent it by calling the `stopPropagation()` method of event object `onclick` of the textbox as follows:

```
$("#container").click(function () {
  $(this).html("<input type='text' onkeypress='return isNumber(event)' onclick='event.stopPropagation();' style='width:35px;' value='" + $(this).text() + "' />");});

function isNumber(evt) {
  evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
  if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/gp3Lu1ej/)

Comment: Code is very large to paste it here. It is complete graph

Comment: @Richa Well is this the case..? are you appending the textbox in an event handler?

Comment: My code  $('.clickme').click(function () {
    if ($(this).find('input').length === 0) {
        $(this).addClass("cellEditing");
        initial = $(this).text();
        $(this).html("<input type='text' style='width:35px;' value='" + $(this).text() + "' />");
    }
});

Comment: @Richa doesn't my answer [fix the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/gp3Lu1ej/1/)?

Comment: Unfortunately not :(

Comment: What is not working here http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/gp3Lu1ej/1/?!

Answer (score 0):

Use `type="number"`

```
$(this).html("<input type='number' style='width:35px;' value='" + $(this).text() + "' />");
```

You can also set restrictions on what numbers are accepted:

See Here [W3School Input Type: number](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_input_types.asp)

Comment: I guess type="number" is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions.